# Set model value in kendo dropdownlist to set selected data

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, model, telerik-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I am using Visual Studio 2013 with Framework 4.0 ASP.NET MVC.

I have used Kendo ASP.NEt MVC UI dropdownlist.

My question here is I have set the dropdownlist data in it and running fine now I want to selected option from dropdownlist to model value:

example:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                        .Name("ddlaccounts")
                        .DataTextField("AccountName")
                        .DataValueField("Id")
                        .SelectedIndex(0)
                        .DataSource(source =>
                            {
                                source.Read(read =>
                                {
                                    read.Action("GetAccList", "Protocol");
                                });
                            })
                    )
```

and I have model class:

```
public class AccountViewModel
        {
            public string AccountName { get; set; }
}
```

Here I want to set selected option in AccountName attribute of AccountViewModel so is there any method or feature available to set in dropdownlist declatration!

Please someone help me to solve this, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**During Binding**

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("ddlaccounts")
    .DataTextField("AccountName")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .SelectedIndex(0)
    .DataSource(source =>
        {
            source.Read(read =>
            {
                read.Action("GetAccList", "Protocol");
            });
        })
    .Value(@(if(Model!=null)?Model.AccountName:""))
)
```

**After binding**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setDropDownValue(dropDownElement,dropDownValue){
    var dropDown= $(dropDownElement).data("kendoDropDownList");
    dropDown.value(dropDownValue);
    //OR $(dropDownElement).val(dropDownValue);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setDropDownValue("#ddlaccounts","Some Value");
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried but gives me an error that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" and I also can't set the value because dropdownlist values coming dynamically.

Comment: Updated with a way to set the value after binding.

Comment: Thanks I will try it